# Declaration of Mobile_Bootstrap::_bootstrap() should be compatible with Engine_Application_Bootstrap_Abstract::_bootstrap($resource = NULL)

Tags: socialengine

When i want a picture to share this error is displayed:

[image: User image]

and browser url is :

```
www.domain.com/activity/index/post?&subject=&privacy=everyone&share%5Bfacebook%5D=0&share%5Btwitter%5D=0&share%5Blinkedin%5D=0&composer%5Bcheckin%5D=&autocompleter=&composer%5Bpeoples%5D=#empty-page-error
```

error log :

```
**2014-08-22T12:30:26+00:00 WARN (4): [2048] Declaration of Mobile_Bootstrap::_bootstrap() should be compatible with Engine_Application_Bootstrap_Abstract::_bootstrap($resource = NULL) (/public_html/***/application/modules/Mobile/Bootstrap.php) [33]
Error Code: 59c540
Stack trace:
#0 /public_html/***/application/modules/Core/Bootstrap.php(866): Core_Bootstrap::_initModules()
#1 /home/clobnet/public_html/clobnet/application/libraries/Engine/Application/Bootstrap/Abstract.php(256): Core_Bootstrap->_initModules()
#2 /public_html/***/application/libraries/Engine/Application/Bootstrap/Abstract.php(207): Engine_Application_Bootstrap_Abstract->_executeResource('modules')
#3 /public_html/***/application/libraries/Engine/Application/Bootstrap/Abstract.php(150): Engine_Application_Bootstrap_Abstract->_bootstrap()
#4 /public_html/***/application/libraries/Engine/Application.php(149): Engine_Application_Bootstrap_Abstract->bootstrap()
#5 /public_html/***/application/index.php(204): Engine_Application->bootstrap()
#6 /home/clobnet/public_html/clobnet/index.php(24): include('/public_html/***/...')**
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is E_STRICT error due to error_reporting(E_ALL) in the application/index.php, disappointment setting if you have PHP 5.4+ (where E_STRICT became part of E_ALL). Details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

And a lot of 3rd party modules produced such error, and it is not easy task to review them all and fix all strict errors, so I prefer commented out this line on production server and use settings from php.ini (error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like `Mobile_Bootstrap` is a 3rd party module and you're using PHP 5.4+. What you should do is either contact the developer you got the mobile plugin from or modify the `modules/Mobile/Bootstrap.php::_bootstrap` to have `$resource = NULL` in method signature.

It should look somewhat like the code below (notice the added `$resource = null`):

```
class Mobile_Bootstrap extends Engine_Application_Bootstrap_Abstract
{
  public function _bootstrap($resource = null)
  {
    // custom module logic
  }
}
```